# FInd smallest value $r$ such that a $n\times r$ matrix exists

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices

The input of my problem is an integer $n\geq 3$.

The output is an integer $r\geq 1$ which must be **as small as possible** such that there is a $(n\times r)$ matrix verifying the following constraints:

- the entries of the matrix are $0$ or $1$.
- all the rows are differerent.
- in each row, there are exactly $\lfloor r/2 \rfloor$ entries equal to $1$.
- for every pair of adjacent rows (and the pair composed of the first and the last rows), there are exactly $\lfloor r/2 \rfloor-1$ common positions where the entries are equal to $1$.
- if we take two pairs of adjacent rows, the pattern must also be distinct between these two pairs (see the example with $r=5$ for $n=7$).

For example, with $n=6$, I have the following matrix with $r=5$:

$M_{6,5}=\begin{pmatrix}1  &   1   &  0   &  0  &   0\\
     1  &  0   &  0    & 0  &   1\\
     0    & 0  &   0 &    1  &   1\\
     0   &  0   &  1  &   0 &    1\\
     0   &  1   &  1  &   0 &    0\\
     0   &  1   &  0  &  1   &  0\end{pmatrix}$

There are $\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor=2$ entries which are equal to $1$ in every row. And for each pair of adjacent rows, there is $\lfloor 5/2 \rfloor-1=1$ common position where an entry is equal to $1$.
For example, if we take the $5$th and the $6$th rows
$\begin{pmatrix}0   &   \color{red}{1}   & 1  &   0 &    0\\
     0   &  \color{red}{1}   &  0  &  1   &  0\end{pmatrix}$, there is an entry where both rows are equal to $1$.

The following matrix respects the first four constraints but not the last one:
$M_{7,5}=\begin{pmatrix}0  &   0   &  1   &  0  &   1\\
     0  &  0   &  0    & 1  &   1\\
     1    & 0  &   0 &    1  &   0\\
     1   &  0   &  0  &   0 &    1\\
     0   &  1   &  0  &   0 &    1\\
     1   &  1   &  0  &  0   &  0\\
     1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Indeed, the pair formed by the rows 2 and 3 has the pattern $\begin{pmatrix}1  &   0   &  0   &  1  &   1\end{pmatrix}$ which is also equivalent to the pattern of the pair composed of the rows 3 and 4. So this matrix $M_{7,5}$ is not valid.

> For a given $n$, how could I find the smallest possible value $r$ such that a $(n\times r)$ matrix as described exists?

Comment: Do you require all rows to be distinct?  Otherwise, you can always take $r=2$ for $n$ even.

Comment: As written this does not seem to be research level.

Comment: More generally, use circulant matrices with r=p, the smallest prime divisor of the input n.  Gerhard "Some Answers Are Too Simple" Paseman, 2016.01.13.

Comment: Yes, indeed, all the rows must have distinct patterns. I changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to list all the $\lfloor r/2\rfloor$-subsets of $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots,r\rbrace$ such that adjacent members of the list have intersection  $\lfloor r/2\rfloor-1$ (see "gray codes for subsets").  Use these as the rows of the matrix and just chop off the rows past the $n$-th.

So the answer is the minimum value of $r$ such that $\binom{r}{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}\ge n$.

ADDED: Gerhard correctly points out that I didn't notice the requirement that the first and last rows need to be minimally different.  This means we are looking at whether the [Johnson graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph) $J(r,\lfloor r/2\rfloor)$ has a cycle of length $n$. I see a claim [here](http://www.b-paper.com/hamiltonian-connectivity-pancyclicity-and-edge-deletion-preserving-the-diameter-of-johnson-graphs-2.html) that this graph is pancyclic, meaning it has a cycle of every length greater than 2. If true, the answer remains that same. But I don't see an author or citation there; what sort of paper is it?

Comment: How does this ensure that the first and last rows have the desired property? Gerhard "Thinks We Have Overlooked Something" Paseman, 2016.01.13

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The link to Johnson graphs allows me to see things more clearly and realize that I was not aware of all the constraints of my problem. Indeed the picture illustrating the Wikipedia article allowed me to quickly find a cycle of length $7$ and then a solution with $r=5$ for $n=7$, which was really surprising! However, it turned out that in my problem, not only the patterns of the rows must be different but also the patterns of "pairs" of adjacent rows must be distinct. I updated the question but you answered my initial (but not complete) question so I accepted it.

Comment: @PaulBub.If your initial question has been answered and you even accepted the answer, it is the usual policy not to modify the question any more after that, but rather to ask a completely new one. Imagine somebody answers the modified one now, than you couldn't accept that answer too!